# Python Regex for all variations of string except containing certain substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-negation

I need to capture code lines that have `<ADDRESS:` string in them. However, I want to ignore the line ONLY if it has `SOME STR <ADDRESS:` i.e. it has `SOME STR` prepended just before `<ADDRESS:`. There may be other words before and after in the line.

I attempted the to identify the regex and it seems to work for use case: https://regex101.com/r/Lc5aKq/1

I am however, unable to get this to work in Python3.

method:

```
def check(self, file):
        regex = r"\(?!.*(SOME STR)\).*\<ADDRESS:*"
        print(f'Content once: {file.content}')
        for match in re.finditer(regex, file.content, re.DOTALL):
            print(f'Regex: {regex}')
            print(f'Content: {file.content}')
            matched_str_offset = match.start(0)
            print(f'Matched offset: {matched_str_offset}')
```

When the second line of method `print(f'Content once: {file.content}')` which prints content of input file gets executed, I get the following correct contents of file including the quotes:

```
ADDR = "<ADDRESSS:qwerty>"

objA = PremilinaryObject(
    code_seg = """<ADDRESSS:qwerty> --paramX=valueX"""
)

objB = PremilinaryObject(
    code_seg = ADDR + """/xyz """
)

objC = PremilinaryObject(
    code_seg = """SOME STR <ADDRESSS:qwerty>/abc.par --paramX=valueX"""
)


objD = PremilinaryObject(
    bash_script= """SOME STR blah blah blah"""
)
```

However, the print statements in the for-loop do not execute, implying he regex is not matching.
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<!\bSOME STR )\<ADDRESS:` https://regex101.com/r/6ibJCb/1

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your code does not match your regex101 example. When you use `r` to make a raw string, you don’t need to escape the parentheses.

So try `regex = r"(?!.*(SOME STR)).*\<ADDRESS:*"`

Comment: I was trying out a couple of variations; hence the difference in regex in the above code and regex101 example. However, I tried the one you suggested but does not work. It now prints `Matched offset: 0` due to the last statement in for-loop implying it is treating the entire file as a single line.

Comment: Try removing the `re.DOTALL` flag